# Print image in .Net winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I am trying to allow my users to print the current page they are on in our WinForm program.  First I take a screenshot of the app and save it to disk.  Then I kick off a `PrintPreviewDialog` and load it in there.

That all works, except for the fact that it goes off the page!  I can't figure out how to change or allow the user to change the page layout for printing to **landscaped** and/or to "**auto fit**" the screenshot to 1 page.

```
private void printDetailsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     HUD.ShellForm.SaveAsImage("CaseNoteDetails.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    printPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.AutoZoom = true;
    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
    printPreviewDialog1.AutoSize = true;
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    float x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
    float y = e.MarginBounds.Top;

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("c:\\CaseNoteDetails.jpg"), x, y);
}
```

---

I changed one line to this -->

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("c:\\CaseNoteDetails.jpg"), x, y,1000,750);
```

and that works except I have almost 1/3 of the printed page as white space.  How do I minimize the Padding/Margins so I can use the whole page?

Comment: To note: I know about this -->http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6he9hz8c.aspx but that does not talk about making the image fit...

Answer (score 3):

The default scaling for PrintDocument is 1 pixel = 0.01 inch.  A typical piece of paper is about 7.5 inches wide (usable space), an image of 750 pixels wide is going to fill it completely.  Surely your screen is wider than that.

Use the Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Rectangle) overload instead so you can rescale the image to make it exactly wide enough.  PageSettings.Landscape lets you rotate it.

Comment: ?  I will give that a try but to be clear, the image is TOO BIG and as such is chopped off at the edge of the page in printer preview and ultimitaly, the printed page.

Comment: No, your image is not too big.  No screen shot could ever fill up a printed page, printers have very high resolutions.  You just need to draw it smaller.  That will make it look better too, the fat pixels you are getting now aren't that pretty.

Comment: I have the image resized now I need to minimize the Padding on the printed page as my image starts a 1/3 of the way across it.

Comment: Tweak the rectangle you pass to DrawImage()

Answer (score 2):

To get landspace

```
  printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true
```

For purposes of resizing, have you tried Image.GetThumbnailImage.  It looks to be a function that can resize an image to make it fit

Also, take a look at these examples

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120825151223/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/kakaiya/archive/2005/06/09/42656.aspx)

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/22079

Comment: The landscape part works great.  I will give the other portion a try though as even on landscape it is a little too wide.

Answer (score 0):

The padding and margins of the print document are controled in the printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings value.